# VBA code that will find a named chart in a Power Point presentation

Tags: vba, loops, charts, powerpoint

I have been able to, with support from site members, create a user form in a Power Point slide to update an embedded chart.  In order to fully utilize the user form, VB code must used to loop through all slides because the named chart may move between slides.  The name of the chart is "DVPVchart".  The code being used continues to get an error at the first Set assignment.  Code is below.  Tried multiple arrangements and variants of the loop but continue to return the same error. Any guidance is appreciated.

```
Private Sub AddDVSetUp_Click()

Dim sld As slide
Dim shp As shape
Dim chrt As Chart
Dim xlWB As Object


    For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides

        Set shp = sld.Shapes("DVPVchart")
        Set xlWB = shp.Chart.ChartData.Workbook

        'Find first sheet of embedded Chart In PowerPoint 
        With xlWB.Sheets(1)

            'location in Chart In PowerPoint = UserForm Textbox 
            .Range("C4").Value = Gate2Date.Value
            .Range("C11").Value = OldestSurrogateDate.Value

        End With

    Next sld

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns error since you didn't put a check if the chart exist in the said slide. You need to add a check if the chart matches your criteria. Try:

```
For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    '/* You will need another loop to check each shape */
    For Each shp In sld.Shapes
        If shp.Type = msoChart Then '/* check for specific type of shape */
            If shp.Name = "DVPVchart" Then '/* chech chart for specific name */
                Set xlWB = shp.Chart.ChartData.Workbook '/* assign it */
                Exit For '/* exit since you got what you need */
            End If
        End If
    Next
    If Not xlWB Is Nothing Then Exit For '/* exit if you already set your xlWB object
Next

'/* Rest of your code go here */
```